# How to create a fixed, vertical, expandabale navbar?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I already read the related questions, which unfortunately do not give an answer to my specific problem:

On the basis of Bootstrap 3.0.3, I am trying to create a fixed navbar on the left with a width of 50px, which should expand to a width of 150px, when you click on the navbar-toogle. When the navbar is not expanded, it should display only the glyphicons for each link. I am able to create the navbar with a fixed width, but I am stuck with the correct incorporation of the navbar-toggle and the the span-text, which is neither displaying nor working correctly. Have a look at the example pictures for the intended result:

[image: Sidebar menu]

[image: Sidebar menu expanded]

**HTML:**

```
<!-- Sidebar -->
<div id="sidebar" role="navigation">
    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>


    <div id="sidebar-nav">
                <ul class="nav nav-stacked">

                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-star"></span>Link1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud"></span>Link2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire"></span>Link3</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart"></span>Link4</a></li>
                    <li><a href="http://stackoverflow.com/"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-send"></span>Link5</a></li>

                </ul>
    </div>
<!-- Sidebar End -->
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
    #sidebar {
    background-color: #16a085;
    color: white;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 50px;
    z-index: 2;

}

#sidebar-nav {
    margin-top: 75px;
}
```

I would appreciate your advice on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/CHe4S/) sort of what you're after? Animations can be done with -webkit-transition on the width. I'll fine tune this when I get the time in half an hour.

```
#sidebar .link-text {
    visibility: hidden;
}
#sidebar:hover .link-text {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that doesn't look bad. I didn't think about animations, but rather thought about using the existing javascript-classes in Bootstrap 3 (the ones for fixed horizontal menus). Good idea. However, the solutions has to work on mobile phones as well.

Comment: I can't see any reason why this wouldn't work on a mobile device? Especially if you're dealing with something fixed width, you can give it static positioning and just wait for a mouseclick.

Comment: Great. I just used the opacity-attribute (0 and 1) instead of visibility, because it didn't seem to work with -webkit-transition.